# 3D Avatar Implementation on Botframework V4

Tags: botframework, chatbot, avatar

I'm searching for knowledge sharing on how to connect a 3D avatar with a bot.
Something like done on Bot Libre https://www.botlibre.com/forum-post?id=682689 .
The implementation can be on WPF, UWP or web.
I'm currently working with Botframework V4.7 and C#.

Thanks in advance,
Amintas

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are wanting to utilize a front end 3D avatar (possibly Bot Libre's) but is instead powered by BF and not Bot Libre's backend bot service, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will likely require you to build a custom connector to pass your bot's incoming and outgoing activities thru to the Bot Libre system. There are examples out there of connectors/adapters that have been built by 3rd parties, such as this [Twilio WhatsApp](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-js/tree/master/libraries/botbuilder-adapter-twilio-whatsapp) adapter, this [Twitter](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-js/tree/master/libraries/botbuilder-adapter-twitter) adapter, or this [Alexa](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Adapters.Alexa) adapter if you are planning on building in C#.

Any adapter you build won't need to be as full fledged as these are as you are only designing for what you know you need, and not for the masses.

You will also need to research Bot Libre to see which API endpoints might be relevant to you. You can see a listing of APIs [here](https://www.botlibre.com/api.jsp). Really, this holds true for any service like Bot Libre that you decide to land on.

Hope of help!

Comment: Indeed Steven. That will definitively require some heavy lifting from my end to accomplish that. Thanks for the guidance!!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Channel your bot is deployed on and what does the channel supports. 
 For example if your bot is deployed in Facebook Messenger, you can achieve this by creating a web page that renders a 3D Avatar and using Bot Framework you can send a web_url button from which the user will press and the web page will open up inside of messenger with the rendered avatar.

Comment: Thx. I'm planning to publish the bot via Direct Line on a website. Would that work the same way? Any recommendation on how to connect the bot with the avatar? A how-to link would be great ;)